# Can Grsec whitelist code which breaches some of its rules?

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, grsecurity

I'm looking into playing around with the Grsecurity kernel on my laptop, a 2012 Retina MacBook Pro, which is running Arch. So far, I've got bits and pieces of experience using SELinux, but that's on very different hardware, so I've never run into the kind of situation that's causing me issues on my laptop.

My laptop uses Wi-Fi hardware which works on both the 2.4 and 5 GHz bands, with two drivers available: one is fully open source and only allows for use of 2.4 GHz (`b43-firmware`), while the other has mostly proprietary blobs and allows for both the 2.4 and 5 GHz modes to work consistently (`broadcom-wl`/`broadcom-wl-dkms`).

The issue is that the proprietary driver performs some illegal memory accesses, which can't be compiled against the `linux-grsec-headers` because of illegal memory access. The Arch Wiki [skims over this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Grsecurity#Compatibility).

I gather that SELinux policies are flexible enough that they'd allow for something like this to be whitelisted, but I'm not sure if, or how this could be done with Grsec, and since SELinux support seems limited in Arch (only available via AUR, with much of the userland tooling missing), I'd like to know if it's at all possible to get this working with Grsec.